# python version compatible for torch==1.7.0+cu101

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I want to run a DNN on GPU with torch. CUDA 10.1 is installed in my machine and one of compatible torch version with CUDA 10.1 is:
(based on this link https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/)

> torch==1.7.0+cu101 torchvision==0.8.0+cu101

What is the compatible python version with this torch version?

**P.S**

There are older versions of torch like 1.4.0 which is compatible with cuda 10.1 (I tried and it worked) but it is compatible with python3.5.2 but it is too old for the other packages that I am using them. I need to use python 3.8 or later versions.
I tried python versions 3.8.1 and 3.9.16 but I got following errors:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.7.0+cu101
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.7.0+cu101
```

I realised that the problem is python version but I don't know which python version is compatible.